# How can I add a taxonomy-based view to a page?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I created a taxonomy with a vocabulary called Series. The Series vocabulary contains a list of terms x, y, z.

I created a content type called Events, which has a field to tag the content with a term from the Series vocabulary.

I created a view to display the events on a page in ascending order beginning from today's date.

The view is set to display certain fields for each piece of Event content. One of the fields displayed is the Series term, which is set to be a link that goes to a page that contains a list of all events tagged with that term.

How can I make that resulting page into a view block that I can drop into a content panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go edit the view that you created and hit add+ next to the view name and then block. By adding a block a new block will appear in the Structure-> Blocks Section and then you can place it anywhere you like.